# Registering a car in Lithuania without being a resident

Tags: vehicle-registration, lithuania

As an EU citizen, do I need a address in Lithuania in order to register a car there?

[Regitra](http://www.regitra.lt/mobile/en/m_vehicle_registration) just states that owner data will be verified against the Lithuanian Register of Residents, and if one is not registered as a resident, the owner needs to provide some proof for the address which will appear in the registration papers, such as an identity card or an apartment rental contract. It doesn't specifically rule out addresses outside of Lithuania.

What about temporary import/export plates?

Answer (score 4):

Got an answer from Regitra today: Temporary/transit plates (red letters on white background) can be assigned to anyone, including persons who cannot provide a proof of residence or regular abode in Lithuania. They have a validity of one month.

Regular (black-on-white) plates require a registered residence in Lithuania. There is a way to get a six-month registration without being officially registered as a resident; this, however, requires some proof of abode such as a rental contract. Bottom line: regular plates are not available to non-residents.

Either way, registering a vehicle requires the following:

- Proof of insurance
- Proof of TA (techninė apžiūra – vehicle inspection), **except** when getting transit plates (red plates) for the first time
- Proof of vehicle identity
- ID of the person registering the vehicle
- Previous registration certificate
- Proof of ownership (e.g. sales contract), **unless** the previous registration was already in the requester's name
- Previous license plates, unless they were lost or returned to the issuing authority